# Calculating the software keyboard height - iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, keyboard

In my Cordova app I'd like to be able to tell if a particular element is offscreen, and scroll it to the center of the viewport if it is. Unfortunately, my calculations all seem to be thrown off by the various sizes of the iOS and Android keyboards -- the height varies based on the keyboard used, whether auto-suggestions are on, whether the screen is in portrait or landscape mode, etc.

On iOS, Cordova has the [cordova-plugin-keyboard](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard) plugin that gives us the height in the [KeyboardHeightWillChange](https://github.com/cjpearson/cordova-plugin-keyboard#keyboardheightwillchange) event. I see that there is *something* in native code for Android mentioned in this blog post: https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2016/keyboard-handling-on-android/. Has anyone found a means to determine the height of the keyboard in Cordova-land on both iOS and Android?

Comment: As far as i checked, this plugin's - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-native-keyboard onKeyboardWillShow &  onKeyboardDidShow options does what you are expecting

Comment: Thanks! I guess I didn't specify that I wanted something that was free (this plugin costs USD $199) -- it never occurred to me that people were charging for their Cordova plugins. :-(

This plugin does register a height for both Android and iOS. Go ahead and write this up as an answer. I'm still hoping for a free solution, but if there's nothing else that will work, so be it.

Comment: posted the answer. But I feel you should be able to negotiate with the author for a better deal by mailing him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i checked, this plugin's - [Cordova native keyboard plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-native-keyboard) onKeyboardWillShow &  onKeyboardDidShow options does what you are expecting.

Unfortunately this plugin is commercial as the author has mentioned that it was a beast to implement. But he is also open for suggestion regarding the costing. You can mail him to check out the options. Cheers